# mysql character_set_results is not changed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I'm using mysql with hibernate and having problems with all other languages then English. I'm getting and exception saying that the language is not utf8 though the language is utf8 (hebrew).

I ran `show variables like '%character%';` and this is what I got:

[image]

I think maybe character_set_server is the problem? it is latin1 and I can't change it to utf8, how do I do it? I'm using amazon RDS and there under parameters group I see utf character_set_server, so I don't understand why its not utf8 above.

On the other hand maybe it's not the problem at all. Any Other suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:**

I managed to change the attached image values to utf8 for everything but still I"m getting the following exception:

```
2016-02-21 08:46:05 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:139 - could not execute statement [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD7\xAA\xD7\xA9\xD7\x95...' for column 'text' at row 1
    ...
    ...
    ...
    2016-02-21 08:46:05 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
    2016-02-21 08:46:05 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Incorrect string value: '\xD7\xAA\xD7\xA9\xD7\x95...' for column 'text' at row 1
    2016-02-21 08:46:05 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    2016-02-21 08:46:05 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:225 - SQL Warning
    java.sql.SQLWarning: Incorrect string value: '\xD7\xAA\xD7\xA9\xD7\x95...' for column 'text' at row 1
```

**EDIT 2:**

So I managed also to fix the exception. It is now saved fine in the DB.
I fixed it by calling the following command for each column:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

My problem now is that the results are returned from DB with question marks.
I still see empty value for character_set_results when calling `show variables like '%character%';`

Comment: Can you share the jdbc code plus the string as readable text of what you try to do? \x looks byte- encoding to me where I would expect \u notations of characters instead

Comment: Again: please Show your Code - your String encoding looks strange

Comment: What code would you like to see? I'm using hibernate, will this help you? I think the problem is that the value of character_set_result is empty and I can't change it, don't know why.

Comment: My main concern is your string showing up as escaped bytes - I would expect escaped characters which will look like \uxxxx do you have some kind of conversion in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `character_set_server` is the problem.

`\xD7\xAA\xD7\xA9\xD7\x95` is hex for the utf8-encoding for 'תשו'.  If it were interpreted as latin1, it would be '×ª×©×•'.

A strange setting is the empty value (empty string?  NULL?)  for `character_set_result`, which controls transliteration during `SELECT`.

Please provide the output of `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` -- If you get hex of `D7AAD7A9D795` for that Hebrew string, then the data is stored correctly, and we should look at the output side.  If not, then the data is stored incorrectly.  Or that `ALTER` messed things up.

Hebrew, in utf8, displayed as hex, is mostly 'D7xx'.

You need utf8 in several places:

- The bytes you are inserting need to be encode in utf8.
- The connection needs to be in utf8.  `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://...&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf-8"/>`
- The table definition needs to say `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- The html output needs `<meta charset=utf-8" />`.
- If data is coming from an HTML form: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Actually it turns out that my fixes from yesterday fixed DB problems. What I didn't have is "application/json; charset=utf-8" for the response. Thanks anyway, you did help me understand that the DB is fine.